# How to print out file with help PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, printing

Is there any way to print out (to cups for example) html file with help PHP (linux server without X) ?

except shell_exec(), system() etc...

And when i mean print html file means print not source code, means print rendered result.
is it possible with help PHP ?

I know thath there is some possibilities like, 
- run X server, 
- run browser,
- exec terminal command which will ask browser open and print out html file

but without  shell_exec is it possible ?

Comment: This will help you - > http://my.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php

Comment: it seems that it's windows only extension

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to render the file yourself into some sort of printable format such as a postscript or PDF file. There is a good PHP5 library to create PDFs from HTML called [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

So generate the HTML output and store it into a string, you may want to use output buffering to do this. See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php).

Then you can use dompdf to render the HTML contents into a PDF file. Storing it into a temp directory probably makes sense if you don't need to keep the file.

Then, you can use the cups cli to print the file, see the [cups documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html). e.g.

```
shell_exec('lp '.$filename);
```

Comment: actually i thought to use cups-pdf virtual printer to convert html into pdf, because mpdf takes 3 sec for one page html. I'm sure that dompdf will take also as lon as much :(. But print out html into pdf with help virtual printer require render it somehow, and this is almost not possible without X